# R twitter latitude and longitude show NA

Tags: r, twitter

I have a code to extract tweets in R, but the latitude an longitude show always as NA. The code I'm using is the following:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter('weather', n=10,lang='en')
t <- twListToDF(tweets)
l <- t[, c("latitude", "longitude")]
```

The output for l is the following:

```
          latitude longitude
1        NA        NA
2        NA        NA
3        NA        NA
4        NA        NA
5        NA        NA
6        NA        NA
7        NA        NA
8        NA        NA
9        NA        NA
10       NA        NA
```

As you see the output is always NA. Any ideas on how to get geo-location?

Comment: The lat/lon values are dependent on the user enabling geolocation on their tweets

Comment: you are right. I've changed it to 1000 searches and I managed to get around 60 entries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latitude / Longitude values are only available if the user enables 'Location' on their tweets. The default is 'off/disabled', so I'd guess you're more likely to not get the lat/lon values.

See the [official documentation](https://support.twitter.com/articles/122236) for reference:

> **Web**
>
> Tweeting with your location is disabled by default for everyone.
>
> **Mobile**
>
> If you choose to toggle on the "Share precise location" button (available on Twitter for iOS version 6.26 or later, and on Twitter for Android version 5.55 or later), your precise location (latitude and longitude) will be associated with the Tweet and findable via API.